# Incorrect behavior of MergeResult jgit

Tags: java, jgit

Used version of `jGit` `4.5.0.201609210915-r`

I have a big file ( around 10k lines) and I have conflict of this file during pulling( or merging).

I have some code for getting conflicting lines :

```
 Git git = getGit();
    Repository repo = git.getRepository();
    ThreeWayMerger merger = new StrategyResolve().newMerger(repo, true);
    merger.merge(repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD), repo.resolve(Constants.FETCH_HEAD));
    ResolveMerger resolveMerger = (ResolveMerger) merger;
    Map < String, org.eclipse.jgit.merge.MergeResult <? >> mergeResults = resolveMerger.getMergeResults();
    org.eclipse.jgit.merge.MergeResult <? > mergeChunks = mergeResults.get(fileName);
    if (mergeChunks == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!mergeChunks.containsConflicts()) {
        return null;
    }
    for (MergeChunk mergeChunk: mergeChunks) {
            ...get merge chunk and convert to my object
            my object has begin-end lines 
            and which version of file I need use (from my commit or another). 
            After I get lines from sides and display on my panel
    }
```

After that, on `mergeChunks` I have a very big sequence. Start of it looks like this :

```
0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 7, 0, 0, 7, 8, 0, 1, 8, 10, 0, 0, 10, 11, 0, 1, 11, 13 ...
```

If I'm correct, we are having the following table

```
ConflictState       sourceIndex      begin        end
0                   0                0            2        //No conflict
1                   1                2            7        //First conflict range
2                   2                2            7        //Next conflict range
0                   0                7            8        //No conflict
0                   1                8            10       //No conflict
0                   0                10           11       //No conflict
0                   1                11           13       //No conflict
...
//about on 15+ I have difference, between begin and end of chunk
0                   1                69           71       //No conflict
0                   0                60           61       //No conflict
0                   1                72           74       //No conflict
0                   0                65           66       //No conflict 
...
//end of sequence
0                   0                10387        10388    //No conflict           
0                   1                11501        11502    //No conflict
0                   0                10389        10390    //No conflict
0                   1                11503        11504    //No conflict
```

I'm trying to parse it over ConflictState and I'm awating I will get sequence like this

```
NoConflict
FirstConflict
NextConflict
NoConflict
FirstConflict
NextConflict
...
```

but `jGit` return very big sequence of NoConflict ( on my scenarios this sequence around 5k). And file contains conflicting line

This is bug of jGit or I do something wrong?

This behavior appears rarely, but in this case I can't normal show difference between conflicting lines.

Comment: If you replicate the same scenario with plain old git what do you obtain?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni In case of using `git mergetool --tool=meld` , I will have normal result of conflicting lines in meld editor